# Creating bins of a column and getting the count in pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a pandas dataframe:

```
item_code    price
   1           15
   1           30
   1           60
   2           50
   3           90
   4           110
   5           130
   4           150
```

We can see that the max price is 150. i want to divide it into 5 bins of 30 each(into new columns) and get the count of occurance of each item code in that price bin.

final df=

```
item_code    0-30    31-60    61-90    91-120    121-150
    1         2         1       0         0          0
    2         0         1       0         0          0
    3         0         0       1         0          0
    4         0         0       0         1          1
    5         0         0       0         0          1
```

i.e `item_code 1` falls twice in the price range 0-30 therefore under column `0-30` put count as 2. `item_code 1` falls once in price range 31-60. Therefore put count as 1.... Similarly for other item codes.

I tried using pd.cut

```
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120,150]
df2 = pd.cut(df['price'], bins)
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Setup**

```
cats = ['0-30', '31-60', '61-90', '91-120', '121-150']
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150]
```

---

**Option 1**
Use `pd.get_dummies` and `pd.DataFrame.join`

```
df[['item_code']].join(pd.get_dummies(pd.cut(df.price, bins, labels=cats)))

   item_code  0-30  31-60  61-90  91-120  121-150
0          1     1      0      0       0        0
1          1     1      0      0       0        0
2          1     0      1      0       0        0
3          2     0      1      0       0        0
4          3     0      0      1       0        0
5          4     0      0      0       1        0
6          5     0      0      0       0        1
7          4     0      0      0       0        1
```

---

**Option 2**
Using numpy's `searchsorted` and some string array addition.

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

bins = np.arange(30, 121, 30)

b = bins.astype(str)
cats = add(add(np.append('0', b), '-'), np.append(b, '150'))

df[['item_code']].join(pd.get_dummies(cats[bins.searchsorted(df.price)]))

   item_code  0-30  120-150  30-60  60-90  90-120
0          1     1        0      0      0       0
1          1     1        0      0      0       0
2          1     0        0      1      0       0
3          2     0        0      1      0       0
4          3     0        0      0      1       0
5          4     0        0      0      0       1
6          5     0        1      0      0       0
7          4     0        1      0      0       0
```

---

If you are looking to sum the like valued `item_code`s.  You can use `groupby` instead of `join`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

bins = np.arange(30, 121, 30)

b = bins.astype(str)
cats = add(add(np.append('0', b), '-'), np.append(b, '150'))

pd.get_dummies(cats[bins.searchsorted(df.price)]).groupby(df.item_code).sum().reset_index()

   item_code  0-30  120-150  30-60  60-90  90-120
0          1     2        0      1      0       0
1          2     0        0      1      0       0
2          3     0        0      0      1       0
3          4     0        1      0      0       1
4          5     0        1      0      0       0
```

---

**Option 3**
A very fast approach using `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

bins = np.arange(30, 121, 30)

b = bins.astype(str)
cats = add(add(np.append('0', b), '-'), np.append(b, '150'))

j, c = pd.factorize(bins.searchsorted(df.price))
i, r = pd.factorize(df.item_code.values)
n, m = c.size, r.size

pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(i * m + j, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m),
    r, cats).rename_axis('item_code').reset_index()

   item_code  0-30  30-60  60-90  90-120  120-150
0          1     2      1      0       0        0
1          2     0      1      0       0        0
2          3     0      0      1       0        0
3          4     0      0      0       1        1
4          5     0      0      0       0        1
```

Answer (score 5):

Add parameter labels to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `size`:

```
cats = ['0-30','31-60','61-90','91-120','121-150']
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120,150]
df2 = (df.groupby(['item_code', pd.cut(df['price'], bins, labels=cats)])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df2)
price      0-30  31-60  61-90  91-120  121-150
item_code                                     
1             2      1      0       0        0
2             0      1      0       0        0
3             0      0      1       0        0
4             0      0      0       1        1
5             0      0      0       0        1
```

EDIT If you want general solution, add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
   item_code  price
0          1     15
1          1     30
2          1     60
3          2     50
4          3     90
5          4    110

cats = ['0-30','31-60','61-90','91-120','121-150']
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120,150]
df2 = (df.groupby(['item_code', pd.cut(df['price'], bins, labels=cats)])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0))
print (df2)
price      0-30  31-60  61-90  91-120  121-150
item_code                                     
1             2      1      0       0        0
2             0      1      0       0        0
3             0      0      1       0        0
4             0      0      0       1        0
```

Comment: @jezrael nice solution, but in your case if for a bin there are no values available, that column won't come in my final dataframe. for eg: if i update `cats = ['0-30','31-60','61-90','91-120','121-150','151-180']
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120,150,180], there should be one column `151-180` with all values 0, but it isn't . I feel piRSquared solution works in all cases
`

Comment: It si not problem, only call reindex. I edit answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` and `unstack`

```
In [3835]: bins = np.array(bins)  # for dynamic labels 

In [3836]: labels = map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format, zip(1+bins[:-1], bins[1:]))

In [3837]: (df.groupby(['item_code', pd.cut(df['price'], bins=bins, labels=labels)])
              .size().unstack(fill_value=0))
Out[3837]:
price      1-30  31-60  61-90  91-120  121-150
item_code
1             2      1      0       0        0
2             0      1      0       0        0
3             0      0      1       0        0
4             0      0      0       1        1
5             0      0      0       0        1
```

Comment: This is right because, if you've price = 0, it is captured for given bins, left is open.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` + `pivot_table`:

```
bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120,150]
labels = ['0-30', '31-60', '61-90', '91-120',' 121-150']

df = df.assign(bins=pd.cut(df.price, bins, labels=labels))\
       .pivot_table('price', 'item_code', 'bins', 'count').fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
bins       0-30  31-60  61-90  91-120   121-150
item_code                                      
1             2      1      0       0         0
2             0      1      0       0         0
3             0      0      1       0         0
4             0      0      0       1         1
5             0      0      0       0         1
```