# creating categorical data from 2 columns - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, intervals

I have a problem with creating a dataframe which holds a time interval where a measurement of temperature is in. As for now the dataframe has its index as time and another column as the measurements and i would like to have the time converted to an interval of 12 hours and the measurement to be the mean of the values in that timelapse.

```
                         measurement
time
2016-11-04 08:49:25    17.730000
2016-11-04 10:23:52    18.059999
2016-11-04 11:02:09    18.370001
2016-11-04 12:04:20    18.090000
2016-11-04 14:26:43    18.320000
```

so instead of having each time related to the measurement i want the mean of the value of let's say 12 hours like this:

```
                                              measurement
time
2016-11-04 00:00:00 - 2016-11-04 12:00:00     17.730000
2016-11-04 12:00:00 - 2016-11-05 00:00:00     18.059999
2016-11-05 00:00:00 - 2016-11-05 12:00:00     18.370001
2016-11-05 12:00:00 - 2016-11-06 00:00:00     18.090000
2016-11-06 00:00:00 - 2016-11-06 12:00:00     18.320000
```

is there an easy way to do this with pandas?

Later i would like to convert the measurements into intervals as well so that the data becomes boolean like this:

```
                                              17.0-18.0   18.0-19.0  19.0-20
time
2016-11-04 00:00:00 - 2016-11-04 12:00:00         1           0         0
2016-11-04 12:00:00 - 2016-11-05 00:00:00         0           1         0
2016-11-05 00:00:00 - 2016-11-05 12:00:00         0           1         0
2016-11-05 12:00:00 - 2016-11-06 00:00:00         0           1         0
2016-11-06 00:00:00 - 2016-11-06 12:00:00         0           1         0
```

**EDIT:**
I used a solution first posted by Coldspeed

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':time.values, 'readings':readings.values})
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='12H'))['readings'].mean()
v = pd.cut(df, bins=[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28], labels=['17-18','18-19','19-20','20-21','21-22','22-23','23-24','24-25','25-26','26-27','27-28'])
```

I know that the bins and labels could have been done but a for loop but this is just a quick fix. 
the groupby function which groups the value of 'timestamp' in the frequency of 12 hours and gets the readings mean value in the timelapse.

Then the cut function is used to categorize the means into their categories.

result:

```
                     17-18  18-19  19-20  20-21  21-22  22-23  23-24  24-25  \
timestamp
2016-11-04 00:00:00      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-04 12:00:00      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-05 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-05 12:00:00      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-06 00:00:00      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-06 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-07 00:00:00      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-07 12:00:00      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-08 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-08 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-09 00:00:00      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-09 12:00:00      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-10 00:00:00      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-10 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-11 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-11 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-12 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-12 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-13 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-13 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-14 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-14 12:00:00      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-15 00:00:00      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
2016-11-15 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
2016-11-16 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
2016-11-16 12:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2016-11-17 00:00:00      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Your index does not match up with your data. Is there really any sense in transforming it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating bins of a column and getting the count in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803556/creating-bins-of-a-column-and-getting-the-count-in-pandas) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut` + `pd.get_dummies`:

```
v = pd.cut(df.measurement, bins=[17, 18, 19, 20], labels=['17-18', '18-19', '19-20'])
pd.get_dummies(v)

   17-18  18-19  19-20
0      1      0      0
1      0      1      0
2      0      1      0
3      0      1      0
4      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to resample by 12 hour chunks, then create dummies.
`pd.cut` is a perfectly acceptable way to cut the resultant data into bins.
However, I use `np.searchsorted` to accomplish the task.

```
bins = np.array([17, 18, 19, 20])
labels = np.array(['<17', '17-18', '18-19', '19-20', '>20'])
resampled = df.resample('12H').measurement.mean()
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(labels[bins.searchsorted(resampled.values)], resampled.index))

                     17-18  18-19  19-20  >20
2018-03-20 00:00:00      0      1      0    0
2018-03-20 12:00:00      1      0      0    0
2018-03-21 00:00:00      0      1      0    0
2018-03-21 12:00:00      0      0      0    1
2018-03-22 00:00:00      0      0      1    0
2018-03-22 12:00:00      0      0      0    1
```

---

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed(int(np.pi * 1E6))

tidx = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('now'), freq='3H', periods=20)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(measurement=np.random.rand(len(tidx)) * 6 + 17), tidx)

df

                            measurement
2018-03-20 06:58:30.484383    17.960744
2018-03-20 09:58:30.484383    18.572100
2018-03-20 12:58:30.484383    17.646766
2018-03-20 15:58:30.484383    19.025463
2018-03-20 18:58:30.484383    17.521399
2018-03-20 21:58:30.484383    17.318663
2018-03-21 00:58:30.484383    19.388553
2018-03-21 03:58:30.484383    19.520969
2018-03-21 06:58:30.484383    19.060640
2018-03-21 09:58:30.484383    17.106034
2018-03-21 12:58:30.484383    22.887546
2018-03-21 15:58:30.484383    18.437271
2018-03-21 18:58:30.484383    18.426362
2018-03-21 21:58:30.484383    20.558928
2018-03-22 00:58:30.484383    22.555121
2018-03-22 03:58:30.484383    17.139489
2018-03-22 06:58:30.484383    17.209499
2018-03-22 09:58:30.484383    19.466367
2018-03-22 12:58:30.484383    21.765692
2018-03-22 15:58:30.484383    19.680785
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.cut()` + `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
df["measurement"] = pd.cut(df["measurement"], bins=[17.0,18.0,19.0,20.0])
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["measurement"])
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: you can use `pandas.TimeGrouper` to group by every 12 h (or any other frequency) and then take the mean of the groups.

`df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='12H')]).mean()`